# Obtain Pessimistic Lock with Unidirectional @ManyToOne mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, locking

I have two entities. `UserWallet` and `UserAddress` , with UserAddress containing `@ManyToOne` mapping to UserWallet.

How can i obtain a `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` lock , when using a `unidirectional` , `@ManyToOne` mapping with `Spring JPA`.

I have this `UserAddress` entity , which has a unidirectional `ManyToOne` mapping with `UserWallet` entity. How can i use Pessimistic locking on the `UserAddress` instance to also take a lock on `UserWallet`.

```
@Entity
public class UserAddress {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable=false)
private String address;

@Column()   
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date createdAt = new Date();

@Column(nullable=false)
private String qrCode;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_wallet_id")
private UserWallet userWallet;

}
```

At the moment I am only able to lock the UserAddress row, and thus I am able to update the UserWallet record in another thread , and hence facing concurrency issues.

Comment: Why didn't you operate this two transaction in a single atomic unit ? Lock both table row until transaction commit, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I have a scenario , where i use different queries to fetch the UserWallet instance -
a) Suppose i have an address (String) then i can get the UserAddress object with help of UserAddressRepository function like - findByAddress, and then get the UserWallet through that userAddress object, and 
b) At some place i use another property to fetch the UserWallet from the UserWalletRepository itself and not through UserAddress.

Comment: Facing the same problem, can you share how you solved it?